# Document Generation Order

Tags: enterprise-architect

I would like to report an UI diagram to a Word file.
I therefore create a template to extract the controls and their notes to a table.

The table, by default, is sorted by the aleph beta order of their names.

Is there a way to order the tabe by the order of the controls on the diagram?

Answer (score 0):

The default options are to order by Tree order, Name, Modified date or Created date, so no diagram position.

What I would do is probably create an SQL fragment and order them in the query. It's a tad complicated, but doable if you know your way around the EA database structure.